# How to select direct child with specified class name in a context

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

All, Forgive me I am not professional of the jquery, I am stuck with figure out the selector as the title show . please help me  thanks.

I have a function like this:

```
function (container)
{
   var selectContentDiv= $("....",container);//I just don't know how to working with the selector context.
}
```

Supposed we the `container` which contains the html structure like the below:

```
    <div class="block-head">
       <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content"><!--I want to get this one-->
       <div class="block-head">
          <h3>test</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="block-content">
          ....
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want to know how to get the direct first child which have the class named `block-content` of the context? thanks.

Comment: first child of what parent?

Comment: Hi, First child of given select context.thanks

Comment: You want to select the `.block-content` or `.block-head` inside it?

Comment: I want to select `.block-content` . thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first child of an element which has a .block-content class, use this:

```
$('div > .block-content');
```

I use a div as your parent element, which you didn't include in your html.

Comment: Hi , @Nelson, what if I want to use selector context ? like $("....",context). thanks.

Comment: Yes you could use that too, given you identify your parent element with a selector, so say your parent element is a div with id called "parent" then you can use `$('.block-content', '#parent');`

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="block-content"><!--I want to get this one-->
       <div class="block-head">
          <h3>test</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="block-content">
          ....
       </div>
       <div class="block-head">
          <h3>test</h3>
       </div>
    </div>
```

from above HTML if you want to find direct child of `block-content`

```
$('.block-content > div.block-head')
```

**EDIT according to Dream Eater Comment**

Above code is added for example where `.block-content` is the parent and `div.block-head` is the child element.

So complete syntax would be.

```
$('parent > child')
```

Comment: @down-voter please add comment so i can correct or learn from mistake i made

Comment: hi , @Dipesh Parmar, Please tell me how to work with the selector context?

Comment: @Joe.wang which selector you want to know....you can also use `.children()` for selecting children element.

Comment: Without knowing what the OP wanted, you are providing a solution. As per the latest comment from the [OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495021/how-to-select-direct-child-with-specified-class-name-in-a-context?noredirect=1#comment21936879_15495021); you answer is totally wrong.

Comment: @DreamEater i read question and OP clearly said `"how to get the direct first child"` so i can guess that `OP` even do not know how to get `direct child` so it does not matter what DOM he want, thats why i gave him example by editing his `HTML` as you can see in answer i have placed two `block-head`....if teaching OP was my fault then sorry for that...SORRY.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I am sorry maybe I did make it clearly. Please help to review my update content .

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('div > block-content')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get you the first occurrence of a div element with class `block-content`:

```
$('div.block-content').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".block-head").next(".block-content")
```

This will give you the first `.block-content` after `.block-head`